# What would be the xpath for this xml snippet, to get to the "datasource" part?

Tags: xml, xpath

My xml is something like this:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
  <extensions></extensions>
  <system-properties>  </system-properties>
  <management>  </management>
  <profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1"></subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.1"></subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
      <datasources>
        <xa-datasource use-ccm="true">
          <xa-datasource-property name="URL">  </xa-datasource-property>
          <xa-datasource-property name="Password">  </xa-datasource-property>
          <xa-datasource-property name="User"> </xa-datasource-property>
        </xa-datasource>
      </datasources>
    </subsystem>
  </profile>
</server>
```

I want to get to the Password part in order to update it

Comment: First off, please edit your question and post a complete and valid xml example, not some abbreviation that cannot be parsed.  thanks

Comment: @OldProgrammer the gist of it is, the tags are not unique, and the attribute such as xmlns (or something else) comes into play in order to specify which branch to select. Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of

```
//*[local-name()='profile']//*[@name='Password']/text()
```

or

```
//*:profile//*:subsystem//*[@name='Password']/text()
```

or alternatively, using the `string()` method:

```
string(//*[local-name()='profile']//*[@name='Password'])
```

or

```
string(//*:profile//*:subsystem//*[@name='Password'])
```

Comment: @gk_2000 - Well, it worked on the previous version of the xml; now you changed the xml; the new one is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, try again; I have removed a syntax error now. Other changes were simply removing the dots and completing the closing tags

Comment: @gk_2000 - Both expressions still work, but added two other options. If they all don't work, there must be something with your xpath processor.

Comment: Note: I removed my comment because I pasted extra info as part of the error message. Below is an edited one:
Xpath /profile/subsystem[@xmlns='urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0']/datasources/xa-datasource[@yyyy='xxxx']/xa-datasource-property[@name='URL'] causes a failure: Invalid expression

Comment: @gk_2000 The xapth expressions are all prefectly valid. There's something else going on. For example, the error message includes this: `xa-datasource[@yyyy='xxxx']`; in the xml in your question, the element `xa-datasource` does not have a `yyyy` attribute; the only attribute it has is `use-ccm` with an attribute value of `"true"`.

Comment: Thanks @Jack Fleeting for confirming that my xpath is right. The trouble however is not with the yyyy thing, as the attribute is present in the xml I am using. I will keep digging.